# AgGrid row autoHeight for custom cell component

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

does enyone know does agGrid autoHeight column property works for cellRendererFramework in ag-grid-angular?

I've tried this but for me it's not working
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-row-height/#auto-row-height

This is my column config

```js
{
    headerName: 'Custom title',
    field: 'title',
    cellRendererFramework: CustomTitleCellComponent,
    autoHeight: true,
    cellClass: 'ag-table-cell-auto-height'
  }
```

CustomTitleCellComponent has different height depending on it's content

Css style for column

```css
.ag-table-cell-auto-height {
  white-space: normal;
}
```

Does anyone know is it possible to use autoheight with ag-grid-angular for cellRendererFramework ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

No, you can't do this for an editor. You have to configure the column for auto row height. See the official documentation at https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-row-height/#auto-row-height

Comment: I dont understand the answer. This is exactly what the question is describing and it does not work for me. Setting autoHeight=true on the column only works if  cellRendererFramework is not used.